# Universal properties in measure theory and probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, category-theory, lebesgue-measure, brownian-motion, representable-functor

Obviously certains construction as for instance the push-forward (direct image) ${\cdot}_{\star}$ can be interpreted in the categories of measurable spaces, measured spaces or probability spaces as universal in the sense that they *represent* a functor.

Nevertheless universality of such constructions is not really interesting, as the aforementioned categories themselves are not very interesting, as measure theory is not about the category of measurable spaces with measurable maps nor is probability theory about probability spaces and measurable maps as, for instance, isomorphic objects in the latter category are not the *same* from the point of view of probability theory. (Think for example of the uniform distribution on $[0,1[$ and a countably infinite sequence of independent coin tosses.)

Rather, I would be interested in for instance

- the Lebesgue measure (or more generally any Haar measure of a locally compact abelian topological group)
- the Brownian motion representing a functor (the Wiener space feels somehow universal to me)
- any given "distribution"

representing a functor. (I secretely hope that these functors would also allow to explain that even if "we do not care about the sample space", some sample spaces look more universal an natural than others ...)

Do I miss the obvious ? If not, are there references about this questions of question somewhere ?

Comment: Tautologically, the functors represented by an object $X$ in a category $\mathcal C$ are isomorphic to $\mathcal C(-,X) : \mathcal C^{\rm op} \to \mathsf{Set}$. So you can just look closely at $\mathsf{Meas}(-,\mathbb R^n)$ when $\mathbb R^n$ means the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space with the Lebesgue measure (or $\mathsf{Meas}(\mathbb R^n,-)$ if you are interested in the functors co-represented by the Lebesgue measure), etc.

Comment: @Pece As $\mathsf{Meas}(X,Y)$ is the set of measurable maps from measurable space $X$ to measurable space $Y$, anything reprensenting $\mathsf{Meas}(-,\mathbb R^n)$ will be a measurable space plus a measurable map. (A so called "universal element".) That these space and map do "represent" Lebesgue's measure I do not understand without more, as no measure are involved so far. Except if $\mathsf{Meas}(X,Y)$ is perhaps the set of measurable maps $f$ between measured spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $\mu_Y = f_{\star} \mu_X$ ? Could you elaborate a bit ?